# Script to fetch result for SQL statement with in condtion have more than 100k unique identifiers

Tags: sql, oracle

Script to fetch result for SQL statement with in condition have more than 100 000 unique identifiers.

For eg;

```
Select * from table1 where column1 in (<more then 100 000 unique ids>);
```

How to create sql statement in Oracle or script in unix using sqlplus to obtain desired result.

Comment: Put the 100k unique identifiers in a table and `where column1 in (select udi from table)`

Comment: Where are the 100,000 identifiers coming from?

Comment: @Siyual: I have one lakh unique values for column1 and I want value for column2 on the basis of column1 but as Oracle can process 1K values at a time in IN condition...so I need to run more than 100 times to get result ...Is there any efficient way to get the result for 100K unique values.

Comment: Yes, put them in a table or collection and either select from that in a subuery, as AlexK. suggested, or join that to your real table.